# Cannot invoke ASMX Method on IIS7.5

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7, asmx, windows-server-2008-r2

I've already been looking for a solution to this the whole day now. I've got problems with asmx webservices on a server of a customer. They seem to be deployed properly as I can call the asmx file without problems. Now when I try to invoke a method, absolutely nothing is happening. The IE is not returning an error message or anything like that. I've added logging mechanisms to the webmethods but they do not log anything, so the method call must be ignored (user rights are set correctly).

In order to understand the problem here, I've deployed both webservices on a test machine. And guess what, they just work fine. I don't know what I am missing here. I hope you have some suggestions. My only guess would be, that somebody must have messed with the IIS config. I even tried to deploy a simple hello world webservice on the server, but no luck as well. I cannot invoke the method.

The services are deployed on a Windows Server 2008 R2, the used .NET Framework is .NET 2.0. The IIS Version is 7.5

If you need more information, please ask right away!

Comment: We don't need any more information. We simply won't be able to help you unless you supply some. Like, what do you mean when you say "when I try to invoke a method"? You mean through the browser? In any case, use Fiddler or something to see what's going on over the wire.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: Your iis is not correctly installed, check the link above.